# google column chart make it responisve

Tags: charts, column-chart

Good day, I have a google column chart and work perfectly but when I re size my browser the column chart overflowed and wont re size. my website is responsive and I dont want to put my bar chart like that. how to get my column chart responsive?

I got this column chart from developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
    <!-- Load Google chart api -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
      ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
      ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
      ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
      ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
    ]);
    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
      },
      bars: 'vertical',
      vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
      height: 400,
      colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3']
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

    var btns = document.getElementById('btn-group');

    btns.onclick = function (e) {

      if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
        options.vAxis.format = e.target.id === 'none' ? '' : e.target.id;
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    }
  }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>        

   <div id="chart_div" style="width:100%;"></div>
 <br/>
<div id="btn-group">
  <button class="button button-blue" id="none">No Format</button>
  <button class="button button-blue" id="scientific">Scientific Notation</button>
  <button class="button button-blue" id="decimal">Decimal</button>
  <button class="button button-blue" id="short">Short</button>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I tried also to add width="100%" from div but its doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the problem with Google Charts is that it doesn't have a responsive feature.

From previous explorations over the web, the best solution that I found and implemented was:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    drawChart();
});
```

This piece of code calls the `drawChart()` function each time the browser window is resized. Therefore, this means that the Chart is redrawn each time. This may not be the best or efficient solution, but for me it did the job.

In order to allow the `.resize()` function, you will require the jQuery Library. More information for this is available [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp).